# Is using hidemyass while in the tor browser safe?

Tags: web-proxy

I have been getting so anoyed with cloudflare everytime I visit a site that I have started to use hidemyass proxy server page while on the torbrowser to get past this. Is this another level of anonimity or does this comprimse tor in some way?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing inherently bad about using a proxy after Tor, if you're ok with pseudonymity rather than anonymity (you're the Tor user that always uses hidemyass). hidemyass is in this instance not that different from a random cdn that also sees a huge amount of your traffic. Of course, they could link your pseudonymous profile to your actual identity if you ever divulge it while browsing.